# is c++'s -Wmultichar a vulnerability or a porting flaw?

Tags: c++, linux, networking, substitution, glyph

I've built a simple substitution cipher that is intended to be used for network communication between Linux devices the current version of the substitution box is as follows:

```
long c_subBox[82] = {
            '꓃', '꓂', '꒿', 'ꐮ',
            '꒫', 'ꎉ', 'ꈽ', 'ꈭ',
            'ꈚ', 'ꈘ', 'ꇬ', 'ꇕ',
            'ꇤ', 'ꄃ', 'ꃉ', 'ꔮ',
            'ꔭ', 'ꕆ', 'ꕥ', 'ꖘ',
            'ꗈ', 'ꗰ', 'ꘚ', '꘠',
            'ༀ', '࿊', 'రௌ',  '௵',
            'g','f', 'a', 'ᚠ',
            'ᚡ', 'ᚹ', 'ᛥ', 'ᛗ',
            'ᛟ', 'ᛤ', 'ᛝ', 'ᛪ',
            'ᛃ', '', '', '',
            '', '', '', '',
            '', '', '', '',
            '', '', '', '',
            '', '', 'ᱫ', 'ᱪ',
            'ᱩ', '᱑', 'ᱨ', 'ᱭ',
            '᱘', 'ᱰ', '᱙', 'ᱟ',
            'ᱴ', 'ᱝ', 'ᱜ', 'ᚘ',
            'ᚙ', 'ᚏ', 'ߎ', 'ߏ',
            '߷', 'ᢆ', 'ᡩ', 'ᢪ',
            'ᢜ', '᠕'};
```

This is the cipher-text substitution box and my concerns are about this following compilation warning:

```
CultCipher.cc:49:24: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
                 'ᢜ', '᠕'};
```

Does this mean that my code will only be able to work on the current operating system?(this is my current goal so this would be good if true). If this causes problems independent of the operating system, is there a way to fix this(obviously the recommended flag gets rid of the warning; but does that mean the problem actually gets fixed?)

Comment: Those symbols definitely occupy more than one byte so you should not use char literals to define them. Use string literal `u8"߷"`.

Comment: I agree with this. Upon doing some char to string conversions I was able to see that my characters where being output as the same value. I'm assuming this is because of binary division. characters such as `"ᚠ"` seem to be divided into multiple negative integer values. `-102` seems to be the most common base value.